# Move camera to a fixed position and axis

Tags: three.js

I've a demo with a 3D model, work with webGL and Three.js, i import orbit, set it and everything work with it.
Now i've the problem to restore a camera position after i've change it with orbit gesture.

The problem is that i want a button that on click repositioning the camera in a way that the model seems to be in a isometric position.

Comment: Have you tried camera.position.set() + controls.target.set() and then animate() ? An isometric view would have angles of 60/120° (you can also use rotation), but 'isometry' means ortho mode ...

Comment: Yes i've found the solution and the problem is only geometric. I use position set and callculate the axys delta rotation angle to reset the rotation.

Comment: I post my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the best solution is the banal one.

1. Position in the classic way the camera and object to lookAt a isonometric vector

   ```
   this.camera.position.set(x,y,z);
   ```
2. Save this position as start position:

   ```
   this.startPosition = this.camera.position.clone();
   ```
3. Use this vector to restore the initial position after Orbit had changed it:

   ```
   this.camera.position.set(this.startPosition.x, this.startPosition.y, this.startPosition.z);
   ```

This is more simple that calculate the rotation's angle computer by orbit and for my porpouse work pretty well.